# Camera calibration validation in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

For validating the calibration of a camera the most used method is the **reprojection-error**.

I am having doubts with `OpenCV` implementation: it uses the same images for extracting the camera parameters and **validating** the camera calibration.

Actually, `cv2.calibrateCamera()` use the images to get `cameraMatix, dist, rvecs, tvecs` that are used subsequantially in the tutorial to calculate the reprojection error and judge the accuracy on that.

> The closer the re-projection error is to zero, the more accurate the parameters we found are. [Source](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)

```py
# Reprojection Error
mean_error = 0

for i in range(len(objpoints)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix, dist)
    error = cv.norm(imgpoints[i], imgpoints2, cv.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    mean_error += error

print( "total error: {}".format(mean_error/len(objpoints)) )
```

I tried to confirm my doubts by having 8 images, and used:

- 6 for finding the camera parameters
- 2 for the validation

Here is the code I tried: [link to gist notebook](https://gist.github.com/ayoubft/9fb12654f3067d9cc28d7faea4c374e6).

***Is this doubt reasonable ?
What I am not doing correctly ?
What I am missing ?***

Comment: What do you mean by "Validation"?
What `calibrateCamera` done is minimizing the total reprojection error.
So, meaning of checking reproection-error for each feature point is just visualizing the result.

Comment: In other words, it is "Did the function fit well to the given data points?" We are not evaluating the goodness of the parameter values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to evaluate some "goodness" of result parameters, you will need some other method.
e.g. evaluating straightness of the straight lines on the undistorted image which created with the parameter values may be one way.

Comment: calibrateCamera does not validate, it only shows the remaining reprojection error after optimization. If you compute the same reprpjection error an additional images you could call that a validation (set).

Comment: It is actually the reprojection part, it make no sense to reproject the points you just made the calibration with. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

Comment: I added some details to give more clarification.

Comment: sure it makes sense to calculate the reprojection error on the images used for optimization. It will tell you how big the error is still on those images. If it is too big, the camera model isn't strong enough, e.g. not enough degrees of freedom. If you compare camera calibration with machine learning, the reprojection error from calibrateCamera is comparable to the training error. If you want to get a validation error for evaluating the generalization, you can do that by computing reprojection error on another set of images with the result-camera-model from the calibration process.

Comment: @Micka, yes I want to do the latter thing and I tried it [here](https://gist.github.com/ayoubft/9fb12654f3067d9cc28d7faea4c374e6); is what I am doing right ?

Comment: If you think so, just do it.
However, how you give the enoughly accurate 3D location of points?

Comment: It seems that, you worry over-fitting or other very poor result.
However, in general, for camera calibration, we do not do such poor work that makes a large difference between the evaluation of calibration results and the evaluation of generalization performance.
In other words, if you give the such sparse or biased data, and the accuracy of "interpolation" with the obtained model can become problem, what is wrong is such your work.
I think this is why nobody do such evaluation you say.

Comment: Of course, no matter how well you give the data, the results may not be good.
However, this can be clearly seen from the reprojection error of the data used for calibration.

Comment: I think that, if you really use only 6 images for calibration, you should reconsider about the validity of such work, at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing camera calibration to machine learning, consider that what you can do to do that is clearly different.

When the measurement space is clearly limited and you can sample as much data as you like from it, you do not have to aim for good generalization performance using only a small amount of data.

When you can used enough amount data which covers the measurement supace sufficiently for function fitting, is it really necessary to consider about the generalization performance of the result?
What is the "generalization performance" at such scene?

Of course, in practice, it is difficult to obtain ideal measurement data. For example, it is difficult to obtain feature points located near the outer edge of the field of view.
It would be valuable if the evaluation is based on such a real problem, but the your form of using 8 images separately in 6 and 2 is nonsense.

You should provide enough data for calibration. If you do so, just checking the reprojection error for the used data will be enough way to estimate the goodness of the result.